# How to add Eventlistener for all Elements in the page which thier ids are inside my Array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener

I have elements with Ids in my page. Also I have an Array, which includes the Ids.

```js
const locations = [{
    "location": "hauptbahnhof",
    "color": "Magenta"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kröpke",
    "color": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "location": "KröpckeUhr",
    "color": "Green"
  },
]
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var ids = locations[i].location;
  console.log(ids);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hauptbahnhof">Hauptbahnhof</div>
  <div id="Kröpke">Kröpke</div>
  <div id="KröpckeUhr">Kröpcke Uhr</div>
  <div id="Drumstreet">Drumstreet</div>
</div>
```

It gives me all locations out. 
Now I want to add Eventlistener for all Objects in my page which the Array includes thier Ids using javascript.

Comment: You already have the logic to log the id.  So what is confusing you about using it to lookup elements and attach event listeners to them?

Comment: EventListener for what? what do u want to listen to?
click? key press?

Comment: @Mara I have lots of such divs and Ids. Also I have The Array which lots of infos are included, So, I taught maybe there is a way which I  don't have to add an Eventlistener to one by one of them.

Comment: @NoamL I want to add onmouseover, click and mouseleave and for every Event, a Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get element by id and add event listener wit function  on it 
`element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);`
For demo purpose the corresponding div will have red color at click.

EDIT after the commnent

Check if the element exist after was search by id:

```
const element = document.getElementById(locationId)
if (element) {
  // add listener
}
```

```js
const locations = [{
    "location": "hauptbahnhof",
    "color": "Magenta"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kröpke",
    "color": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "location": "KröpckeUhr",
    "color": "Green"
  },
  {
    "location": "nonExistingElement",
    "color": "Green"
  },
]

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var locationId = locations[i].location;
  console.log(locationId);
  const element = document.getElementById(locationId)
  if (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      element.style.color = "red";
    }
  } else {
    // ID is not in the html elements
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hauptbahnhof">Hauptbahnhof</div>
  <div id="Kröpke">Kröpke</div>
  <div id="example">no event on this</div>
  <div id="KröpckeUhr">Kröpcke Uhr</div>
  <div id="Drumstreet">Drumstreet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the Problem is if there is no such id in the page, the code won't run.
TypeError: element is null

Comment: Thanks alot, could you tell me how to console.log another attributes of the current element?
for Ex: when I click on houptbahnof, it show the color of houptbahnof (which is in the Array written) in the console.log.

Comment: This is something else, but the steps you can follow are this: 1. take the clicked element 2. search in your array the corresponding object after id 3. access other properties from the object that you found

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understood you correctly, but is this what you want?

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(locations[i].location).addEventListener("click", function(){
    //
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add click listener on document and the check if clicked items matches

```js
const locations = [
  {"location": "hauptbahnhof", "color": "Magenta"},
  {"location": "Kröpke", "color": "Yellow"},
  {"location": "KröpckeUhr", "color": "Green"},
];

const ids = locations.map(l => l.location);

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target.id);
   if (ids.indexOf(e.target.id) > -1) {
     console.log('Do something here');
   }
});
```

```html
<div  id="container">
  <div id="hauptbahnhof">Hauptbahnhof</div>
  <div id= "Kröpke">Kröpke</div>
  <div id = "KröpckeUhr">Kröpcke Uhr</div>
  <div id= "Drumstreet">Drumstreet</div>
</div>
```